# My new 2020 MacBook Pro is getting very hot

Tags: macbook-pro

I got this laptop roughly a week ago and have not used it for anything too computationally extensive as of yet. Using it on Zoom has got my laptop incredibly hot, yet the use on my CPU doesn't peak about 20% according to activity monitor.

Is this a defective laptop, or is it just how they usually work?

Answer (score 1):

Using any teleconferencing software (Zoom, Google Meet, Cisco WebEx) puts a heavy load on the CPU and the GPU processing the video stream. My 2019 MBA's fans ramp up and the Mac gets hot when participating in a Zoom with 10 people.

My iMac at home, with a dedicated GPU and a very fast Core i9 CPU, shakes it off and barely breaks a sweat, even in Zoom calls with many more participants.

Which 2020 MBP are you using? The 13" does not have a dedicated GPU, whilst the 16" has an additional AMD Radeon Pro GPU of various flavours, depending on the build.

Comment: 13” (sorry should have included that). All I have is the additional ram.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a defective laptop, or is it just how they usually work?

It's impossible to tell judging by the *single* performance metrics of single *application* in a singular environment.  However, IMO, Zoom is a blatant security disaster from the get go:

- [routing calls through servers ***in*** China](https://www.businessinsider.com/china-zoom-data-2020-4)
- [atrocious privacy ah\nd security (also linked to China)](https://www.economist.com/business/2020/06/20/can-zoom-be-trusted-with-users-secrets)
- [Flawed encryption gives access to webcam and microphones](https://www.securitynewspaper.com/2020/04/03/zoom-encryption-contains-a-chinese-backdoor-and-uses-data-mining-to-find-your-linkedin-profile-and-sell-your-information/)
- [LinkedIn Back door](https://www.securitynewspaper.com/2020/04/03/zoom-encryption-contains-a-chinese-backdoor-and-uses-data-mining-to-find-your-linkedin-profile-and-sell-your-information/)

The devs at Zoom seem to be focusing on a lot (as in a sh*t ton more - it's a metric value) on just what private data they can see what they can abscond with.

> Is this a defective laptop, or is it just how they usually work?

More than likely not. Note, that I'm not saying it's impossible for a defect to sneak through quality control; it can happen.  However, with Zoom on your plate, I would tale a long hard look at that that software and why you have it installed.  However, I heed these words of wisdom from some of the investment gurus:

> > In the mornings I have  Maria Bartiromo and Dagen McDowell (major crush on her) as well as the the folks from CNBC Squawk Box (Becky Quick and Joe Kermam.  All have a short term bullish outlook on the stock but as contrarians, they all think it's going to get hammered for it's lackadaisical approach to security.  As Dagan put it (paraphrasing) "I will not Zoom now or ever,  I won't connect with anyone who does, - I don't care if you're a business colleague or or family- it's not happening.

On a more technical note, I use Skype and it doesn’t put any load on my CPU or GPU.  Likewise fir Cisco, WebEx, and even Citrix GotoMeeting. I have a disposable Android phone for WhatsApp (Facebook is another nefarious data collection company) and no other app  consume CPU resources like Zoom does.  The best advice I can give you is to avoid it at all costs.

Comment: *as in a sh_t ton more - it's a metric value*  Surely *ton* is an Imperial measure !  I think the metric equivalent is *tonne merde* ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark you’re right if course. This US system of sometimes  using metric and other times imperial confuses the heck out of me.  I’m still trying to figure out this centimeter to fluid ounces thing

Comment: Sometimes one can't avoid using Zoom, especially when the boss, (who is über security-conscious and doesn't want to touch it,) is overruled by _his_ boss.

Comment: Being IT, I tend to have sway over what the bosses use.  I put it in terms they understand...how much is a “zoom bomb” worth to your public perception?  All the security training we  spend  hundreds of thousands on, is it worth bypassing all of that for this trendy piece of software? I put that in an email so if the fecal matter hits the fan, the board of directors will ultimately have one person to focus on and it’s not anyone in IT.   So, regardless of their position, bosses like to cover their posterior, too.

Comment: We needed to use Zoom for our remote teaching for > 1500 students and > 150 faculty for 2 and a half months. There are elements in Zoom, like breakout rooms, etc, which proved very helpful for instruction. Google Hangouts Meet just didn't cut it. We are aware of the Zoom security concerns. If somebody wants to hack in and learn their ABCs or work on the quadratic formula, we were fine with that. Administrative videoconferencing was done through Google Hangouts Meet at my boss' insistence. He's the Head of IT.

Comment: *If somebody wants to hack in and learn their ABCs or work on the quadratic formula, we were fine with that*. Ever been on a Zoom call that got got Porn bombed?  An affiliate school did and is now facing a massive law suit.  It’s simply not worth the price.  I was praised for sticking to my guns on using MS Teams and  even in some cases OBS.